# Error shown when decompiling .apk file for .xml files using apktool

Tags: android, apktool

I wanted to decode a .apk file to java and xml files. For this I followed the tutorial provided in this link - http://comptech-blogger.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-get-source-code-from-apk-file.html. I have got the java files but I'am having problem in the process of getting the xml files. When I wrote the command - apktool d filename.apk - in the command prompt, it shows the following message:

```
d[ecode] [OPTS] <file.apk> [<dir>]
    Decode <file.apk> to <dir>.

    OPTS:

    -s, --no-src
        Do not decode sources.
    -r, --no-res
        Do not decode resources.
    -d, --debug
        Decode in debug mode. Check project page for more info.
    -f, --force
        Force delete destination directory.
    -t <tag>, --frame-tag <tag>
        Try to use framework files tagged by <tag>.
    --keep-broken-res
        Use if there was an error and some resources were dropped, e.g.:
        "Invalid config flags detected. Dropping resources", but you
        want to decode them anyway, even with errors. You will have to
        fix them manually before building.
b[uild] [OPTS] [<app_path>] [<out_file>]
    Build an apk from already decoded application located in <app_path>.

    It will automatically detect, whether files was changed and perform
    needed steps only.

    If you omit <app_path> then current directory will be used.
    If you omit <out_file> then <app_path>/dist/<name_of_original.apk>
    will be used.

    OPTS:

    -f, --force-all
        Skip changes detection and build all files.
    -d, --debug
        Build in debug mode. Check project page for more info.

if|install-framework <framework.apk> [<tag>]
    Install framework file to your system.
```

I really cannot understand where the problem is. I followed every steps that was included in that tutorial. Please help.

Comment: this is not a programming question

Comment: flags require - for shorthands and -- for the full name